# CRUD operations on subdocuments in eve

Tags: flask, eve

Is there a way to directly expose CRUD operations on subdocuments in Eve? Let's say I have a resource `user` like this:

```
{
    "_id": _,
    "name": _,
    "cart": {
        "products": [{...}],
        ...
    }
}
```

I can, of course, use all CRUD operations at `/users/` to update the cart. But is there a way that I could directly access `/users/1/cart/` and get

```
{
    "products": [{...}],
    ...
}
```

So that I could also update the cart by e.g. sending a PATCH request with:

```
{
    "products": [{...}, {...}, {...}],
    ...
}
```

Otherwise you have to assume knowledge on the complete structure and be careful with not overriding other information of the item.

Answer (score 0):

Python-Eve do not support multiple layers embeddings. This feature is about serialization on GET requests. There’s no support for POST, PUT or PATCH of embedded documents, 
Whereas Document embedding is enabled by default. [Python-Eve Official docs](https://eve.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.1/features.html#limitations)